# `md-icon` doesn't work while setting html using jquery

Tags: jquery, angular, icons, angular-material

I need to append `md-icon` to a div. Below code should speak more.

```
$('#test').html('<md-icon class="material-icons">mic_on</md-icon>');
```

This just displays `mic_on` instead of icon.

I think I'm missing something very basic.

Answer (score 0):

As far as Material Design icons, I could not find a 'mic_on' icon at the [Icons Page](https://material.io/icons/). Could it just be the reference is wrong and you meant 'mic'?

Comment: Well its old version reference I'm using which still works! Icon works on rest page!

Comment: I may need more info then. I just tried it on JSBin and it works. Here is the [example](https://jsbin.com/gosuxegago/edit?html,js,output)